# Routing Pulseaudio to JACK causes glitches

Tags: pulseaudio, jack

In these days I'm trying to play my guitar through my audio interface using guitarix and JACK and they work just fine.
The issue arrives when I also want to play spotify or youtube in the meantime. I'm trying to route Pulseaudio to jack executing these scripts after the startup on qjackctl:

```
pactl load-module module-jack-source;pactl load-module module-jack-sink
```

The connection works, but then the sound that I get from my speaker is just terrible, full of glitches and strange noises, it just isn't usable.

Am I doing something wrong? Should I tweak something? Is this setup usable for you?

Comment: if you only want audio playback from Pulseaudio and don't need to capture connection, just use 'pactl load-module module-jack-sink'

Comment: are you just loading Guitarix, which is starting JACK ? suggest you use QjackCtl to start JACK and monitor the server. Suspect your settings for samplerate, buffer size and periods/buffer are set too low and is causing errors in audio stream (x-runs). if qjackctl confirms there are many x-run errors, increased buffer settings will stop this, but might increase audio delay through JACK