# Replace PulseAudio with Jack Audio Connection Kit without sound distortion

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, jack

I am trying to get Jack Audio Connection Kit Working on Ubuntu 16.04.
Initially I tried pulseaudio-jack-modules and enabled it using pacmd

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-jack
pacmd load-module module-jack-sink channels=2
pacmd load-module module-jack-source
pacmd load-module module-jack-source
```

This led to crackling and distorted audio once jack was started. I tried changing bitrate and other settings.

Next I tried completely uninstalling pulseaudio
`sudo apt purge pulseaudio`

This completed stopped all audio.
When I started qjackctl, while also attempting to play a youtube video, I had 2 system inputs and several system outputs. Connecting them did not change anything, I still could not hear anything.

I would like to have clean audio through Jack s.t. I can route audio from different devices properly and not worry about terrible distortion and crackling.

Also I have tried this post's responses and several others.

- "[Routing Pulseaudio to JACK causes glitches](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038381/routing-pulseaudio-to-jack-causes-glitches)"

Comment: First off all, reinstall pulsaudio. Otherwise you will not be able to listen audio from applications which don't support jack. Most applications support pulseaudio, not jack.

Comment: With pulseaudio installed, the audio is distorted to the point where you can barely make out a few words from audio.

Comment: You need pulseaudio for most applications, jack will not receive audio streams from your webbroswer, for example. jack is NOT a replacement for pulseaudio. What are your hardware specs, how is jack configured (sample rate, buffersize, periods)?Why do you want to use jack at all? Please add additional information via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1169221/edit) to your question.

Comment: if audio is distorted in Pulseaudio it has to be fixed in Pulseaudio. maximum level can be 150% in pulseaudio and v likely to be distorted. keep it to 100% or lower